# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'ABC113973' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing TWO MAJOR PROBLEMS!!

PROBLEM 1:

I have two tables and want to show the required data into a specific gridview by using UNION in SQL. Table 1 contains columns {[Date] datetime, [Head] nvarchar(50), [Details] nvarchar(360), [ExpId] int, [Amount] decimal(18,2)}
Table 2 contains columns {[Purchase_Date] datetime, [VendorName] nvarchar(50), [Remarks] nvarchar(50), [Bill_No] nvarchar(50), [AmountPaid] decimal(18,2) }

My stored procedure is;

```
DECLARE @Ledger TABLE
    (       
    DATE DATETIME,
    DESCRIPTION NVARCHAR(350),
    REF_NO NVARCHAR (50),
    AMOUNT INT      
    )

INSERT INTO @Ledger
    SELECT  
        [Date], [Head] + ' - ' + [Details], [ExpId], [Amount] 
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Table1]
    UNION  
    SELECT  
        [Purchase_Date], 'PURCHASE' + ' ' + [VendorName] + ' ' + [Remarks], [Bill_No], [AmountPaid]  
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Table2]

SELECT * FROM @Ledger
```

When is execute the query I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'ABC113973' to data type int.

I wonder why its throwing this error when I try to execute it without Table1 it's fine. Is is due to the column `ExpId` with datatype `int`? If yes then how to deal with it?

PROBLEM 2:

In the above `@Ledger` table when I change `Amount` datatype to `decimal(18,0)` as I want to show the result in decimal figure it throws error

> Conversion failed when converting varchar into numeric

sort of error. as the datatype of amount columns of both the actual tables are `decimal(18,2)`.

Can anyone tell me the solution and the reasons of this problem? Thanks

Comment: what is datatype of column ExpId in table 1

Comment: Please see the edited question. the datatype is INT for ExpId.

Comment: this is the cause of error , the columns in union must have same datatype..seebelow answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
DECLARE @Ledger TABLE
    (       
    DATE DATETIME,
    DESCRIPTION NVARCHAR(350),
    REF_NO NVARCHAR (50),
    AMOUNT INT      
    )
INSERT INTO @Ledger
    SELECT  [Date], [Head] + ' - ' + [Details], CAST([ExpId] AS NVARCHAR(50)), [Amount]  FROM [dbo].[Table1]
    UNION  
    SELECT  [Purchase_Date], 'PURCHASE' + ' ' + [VendorName] + ' ' + [Remarks], CAST([Bill_No] AS NVARCHAR(50)), [AmountPaid]  FROM [dbo].[Table2]
SELECT * FROM @Ledger
```

You are getting an error because you are trying to insert `bill_no` and `expid` into a `varchar` column,but the data type of both fields are `int`. So, you will have to either `cast` or `convert` the `int` values and then insert it into the table.

**Edit:**

If you want to store the amount in Ledger table as decimal then change the data type of amount column to `decimal(18,2)` and make sure that columns of both the actual tables are also of the same data type.

```
DECLARE @Ledger TABLE
    (       
    DATE DATETIME,
    DESCRIPTION NVARCHAR(350),
    REF_NO NVARCHAR (50),
    AMOUNT DECIMAL(18,2)
    )
```

Comment: GREAT!! It solved half of the problem but what about the second Problem? Any solution for that?

Comment: Works Great mate !! Thanks a million. Well now there is another issue and that is i have added a new column in @Ledger i.e. ReceivedAmount Decimal(18,2) because one of the table contains [ReceiveAmount] decimal(18,2) but in table1 and 2 i dont have this column so i added ' ' into the select statements. its throwing error that "Error converting varchar to numeric" any solution for this please?

Comment: @Omer If it's a new issue, you can pull out another question with proper deatils and post the url in the comment.That will help us a lot to solve your issue and might be helpful to others as well.

Comment: @Omer Don't pass `''` instead pass `NULL`, that should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks mate! I actually sorted this out as well by simply CAST(' ' As INT) and works like magic.